# Pass model value from view to controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How I can pass data from view to controller? Please explain how can I pass `ID` to `AAA`?

I have model:

```
public class ABCDE
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Surname { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> MMM { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model IList<Jednoslad.Models.ABCDE>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Layout/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var m in  Model)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("AAA", "BBB"))
    {
        <div class="moto">
            <h1>@m.ID</h1>
            <h2>@m.Name</h2>
            <input type="submit" name="model" value="AAA"/>
        </div>         
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AAA(ABCDE model)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The `ID` and `Name` have to be in an form element, if you don't want the user to edit it put it in a hidden field

Comment: You means @Html.HiddenFor ?

Comment: Yeah thats the proper way to do it since you are using MVC

Comment: hymm but, in controller model is null :(

Comment: if you still have a problem, please edit the question to show us you updated code, so we can be sure exactly what you did.

Comment: your code only displays the text and you need to encapsulate your fields in <input> elements, see my answer

Comment: using Html.EditorFor() will encapsulate those fields for you and your form data is bound to your model object automatically when you submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Html.EditorFor()

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AAA", "BBB"))
{
    <div class="moto">
      <h1>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ID)</hi>
      <h2>@Html.EditorFor(m =>m.Name)</h2>
        <input type="submit" name="model" value="AAA"/>
    </div>
}
```